# Laravel 5 Nice URL

Tags: url, laravel-5

I'd like to set up some nice URL for my website but my issue is that my GET parameters are not all always filled.

For instance I can have all these different parameters:

```
?brand=BMW&model=i8+m4&location=USA
?brand=BMW&location=USA
?brand=BMW+Audi
```

However I'm not too sure if I should create a route for all the different scenarios I could have or if there is any other way to have some nice URL?

I'm thinking of what it could look like:
`/brand/BMW+Audi/location/USA/model/i8` ?

But if I have to create a route for every scenarios it could become very long!

```
Route::get(/brand/{brand})
Route::get(/brand/{brand}/location/{location})
Route::get(/brand/{brand}/model/{model}/location/{location})
Route::GET(/location/{location})...
```

Otherwise I can also create some dynamic parameters such as:

```
Route::get(/{param_1}/{value_1})
Route::get(/{param_1}/{value_1}/{param_2}/{value_2})
Route::get(/{param_1}/{value_1}/{param_2}/{value_2}/{param_3}/{value3})
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume this is for a search of some kind yes?
In that case i would go with the dynamic route since not all parameters have to be filled so in theroy you could use just one of the parameters, and then just add /search before first parameter maybe.

Comment: Yes but that's a bit more complicated than that - This is a 1 page application that refreshes the content dynamically with some apis but update the url without reloading the page.

Comment: you might check this tutorials about laravel crud. https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think get parameters are a perfect solution. But if you do want 'pretty URL's' you could do something like:

```
Route::get('/brands/{brand}', 'BrandController@search');
Route::get('/brands/{brand}/{model}', 'BrandController@search');
Route::get('/brands/{brand}/{model}/{location}', 'BrandController@search');
```

And then in your BrandController:

```
public function search($brand, $model = null, $location = null)
{
    //
}
```

This way the `$model` and `$location` or optional. You can also make `$brand` optional: `$brand = null`. But the routes now require at least one parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I don't understand in your example how this would work if I only have : /brands/{brand}/{location}. It's going to think that my location is actually my model.
That's why I think the dynamic parameters are maybe a better option then

Comment: I don't think you can solve that problem without named parameters. So you need the GET parameters after all.

Comment: Yep I think you're right. I tried with dynamic parameters in my route but it seems to go straight to my error page. Thanks!